# Image processing using Gabor filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, gabor

I need to compare images using Gabor filter. I cant seem to understand how to find a quantifiable value to compare through Gabor. 
Can someone give me steps to do the same. I got some code, but it doesnt compare two images.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Gabor can be used as a filter bank in order to extract texutre 
features from an image (or image patch).
To compare images (or patches from image) using gabor I would follow the following pipline:

1. compute a filter bank from the Gabor (different scale and orientation)

[image: Filter bank]

2. post process to create new feature. you can compute the energy, and first statistics measures on the filtered images.
3. now that you have a vector of features for each image you need some measure to compare tham. You can use simple L2, or fisher criterior as some papers offer [Comparison of Texture Features
   Based on Gabor Filters](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/da63/afb51227077079f539a60dd4047618ac3026.pdf)

Please also take a look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059462/comparing-textures-with-opencv-and-gabor-filters) that is simmilar to yours.